# Only allow strings within EditText

Tags: android

I want to only allow strings to be entered within an EdiText, at the moment the user can enter int and strings.

Is there easy way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to limit what a user can place in an `EditText` is via XML and the property inputType.  Check out the available values [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType).  However, an integer is a character just like a letter and can be part of a string.  So glancing at the list I don't see a built in method that won't accept an integer but will accept letters.

So what you will probably have to do is override a listener for the EditText and write your own method that will test for characters 0-9 and prevent them from being entered in.